# How to change joomla module and install it

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-module

I have problem. I want to change html code of my joomla module, but I already have that module installed, and I need it. When I try to install changed version I got message that I already installed that module, so i guess that I need to change some names in xml file, but i don't know which ones.. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to install changed version I got message that I already installed that module

Check your Joomla module xml file have method="upgrade":

```
<extension type="module" version="3.1" client="site" method="upgrade">
```